# Choppy Recording of Desktop Effects

Tags: nvidia, compiz, video, opengl, screencast

I'm attempting to record a demo of the KDE desktop effects on my computer.  All seems to be working well, except for when rotate the cube, at which point it gets choppy.  [See this video](http://youtu.be/9A00Q6iUdrc) for an example.  I've successfully pulled this off on other computers in the past but for some reason this one's giving me trouble.  As my recorder I'm using Kazam and my graphics card is a GeForce 8400 GS.  I've also tried this with RecordMyDesktop and have tried using Kazam to output the video to both mp4 and mpeg formats.  Any ideas as to what might be going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out after some trial and error.  I had "Flipping" enabled in my NVidia settings.  When I disabled it, all was well.